# Java Spring: Cancelling a Future

Tags: java, spring

I have a method that creates a future:

```
@Service
public class TestService {
    @Async
    public Future<TestClass> testCancelFuture() throws InterruptedException  {
        TestClass testClass = new TestClass();
        testClass.loop();
        return new AsyncResult<TestClass>(testClass);
    }
}
```

And this is my TestClass

```
public class TestClass {
    public void loop() throws InterruptedException  {
        for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
            System.out.println("[" + i + "] loop");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I invoke the method testCancelFuture and cancel it:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController() {
    @Autowired
    TestService testService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET) 
    public String testMethod () throws InterruptedException {
        Future<TestClass> test = testService.testCancelFuture();
        test.cancel(true);
        return "test";
    }
}
```

I would expect the loop to stop , as i cancel the future soon after starting it. However the loop keep going. So, how can I stop the loop in the future ?

Comment: post the `cancel()` method's code

Comment: cancel() is hardly guarenteed once started.

Comment: Your code won't compile as `Thread.sleep` is declared as throwing an exception. You need to handle it.

Comment: Also see possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536555/utility-of-future-cancelboolean-method

Comment: If your `cancel` comes while your thread is sleeping, then you will get an `InterruptedException`. If it comes outside, you don't handle it, so the loop keeps going.

Comment: Check out Spring's source code : `AsyncResult.cancel(boolean)` does nothing and always returns `false`, which means the task could not be cancelled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cancelling / interrupting a running task is never guaranteed. Have a read at [`Thread.interrupt()` method description](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29):

> If this thread is blocked in an invocation of the wait(), wait(long),
>   or wait(long, int) methods of the Object class, or of the join(),
>   join(long), join(long, int), sleep(long), or sleep(long, int), methods
>   of this class, then its interrupt status will be cleared and it will
>   receive an InterruptedException.
>
> If this thread is blocked in an I/O operation upon an interruptible
>   channel then the channel will be closed, the thread's interrupt status
>   will be set, and the thread will receive a ClosedByInterruptException.
>
> If this thread is blocked in a Selector then the thread's interrupt
>   status will be set and it will return immediately from the selection
>   operation, possibly with a non-zero value, just as if the selector's
>   wakeup method were invoked.
>
> If none of the previous conditions hold then this thread's interrupt
>   status will be set.

If your task regulary invokes one of those methods listed then there's a higher chance you'll get more responsive cancellation.

Otherwise the thread might just keep running as if the cancellation is ignored. One way to improve this is to split your task into smaller chunks that checks whether it should keep running in between.