# How to stop a called static method in doInBackground() of SwingWorker

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I have a SwingWorker called Task1,

```
class Task1 extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {
        @Override
        public void doInBackground() {
            String[] args = {};
            try {
                FeatureSetBuilder.main(args); //<---It is a static method


            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
        public void done() {

            UISettings.FP_GENERATOR_DIALOG_2.cancelButton.setEnabled(true);
            loadingDialog.progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
            loadingDialog.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
```

And I have a button that will execute Task1,

```
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("FeatureSetBuilder - Start");
                String[] args = {};
                try {
                    task1 = new Task1();
                    task1.execute();
                    loadingDialog.popOut(task1);
                    task1.cancel(true);



                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("FeatureSetBuilder - Finished");

            }
```

When I click this botton, a dialog with a progress bar will pop out to indicate that the method FeatureSetBuilder.main(args) is running. When task1 completes, the method done() will then be called and close that dialog.

It works fine.

I want to add a Cancel button to that dialog so the user can terminate task1 whenever he wants.

Here is my Cancel button,

```
 cancelButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Stop the current SwingWorker");
                    task.cancel(true);
                    setVisible(false);
                }
            });
```

When I press the the Cancel button, the task 1 seems being terminated as "FeatureSetBuilder - Finished" is printed out. However, the static method FeatureSetBuilder.main(args) is still running.

Comment: This has little to do with Swing and all to do with -- `"how do I stop running Java code?"` First thing I'd do would be not to run another class's main method, but rather make the code more OOP-compliant. Next I'd look into some notification mechanism to allow any process to ask the running code to cleanly stop itself. As expected, the devil will be in the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `doInBackground` method should be periodically checking whether the task has been cancelled. Example from `SwingWorker` class' javadoc:

> ```
> @Override
> public List<Integer> doInBackground() {
>     while (! enough && ! isCancelled()) {
>             number = nextPrimeNumber();
>             publish(number);
>             setProgress(100 * numbers.size() / numbersToFind);
>         }
>     }
>     return numbers;
> }
> ```

I really recommend that you read the javadocs of all classes/methods in `SwingWorker` and related classes. `EventDispatchThread` related problems can be very tricky.

Comment: And see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536555/utility-of-future-cancelboolean-method

Comment: Besides checking for `isCanceled`, since OP is calling `task.cancel(true)` I would also handle interruption (as in `InterruptedException ` and `Thread.interrupted()`). Relevant Oracle Tutorial pages: [Canceling Background Tasks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/cancel.html), [Interrupts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html).

Comment: I get it. Thank you so much