# Java hasNextLine(), nextLine without giving file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have program that gets file `java program < file.txt` and i want to make exception for case when user dont give an file input just: `java program` but I couldnt find any exception for that and when I am trying to check it with

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String tmp;
    try {
        tmp = input.nextLine();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        return 0;
    }
```

nothing happens.

Comment: `throw new IllegalArgumentException(“Expected ‘java program’”);`? If that’s not sufficient you can make your own `Exception` subclass by extending it.

Comment: The problem is it goes to the try but then stops, program dont end but its just stopping and nothing is happening

Comment: Any reason for using the "<" for reading the file?

Comment: @sadge_user: it’s scanning for input. It won’t continue until it gets some. Are you meaning you want a timeout if someone doesn’t provide any input at all?

Comment: @BeUndead yes, I want to exit program if user doesnt provide any input

Comment: Then [that’s been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61843625/2478398)